# Is it possible to filter files in Karma?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

We are using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html) for testing and I can easily run the full suite with:

```
karma start
```

Is there a way I can run a single file without having to comment out all the files I don't want to run in the `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: Which testing framework are you using Jasmine/Mocha ?

Answer (score 1):

you can't run for a particular file name but you can filter by the expression

```
Karma run
karma run -- --grep=filteredtestexpr
```

It doesn't filter by filename, rather by the testdescription's regular expression.

and yes this works with karma-mocha https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha

See if it helps you.